# Grub rescue mode ls not listing

Tags: grub2, ls

In grub rescue mode when I type ls (hd0,msdos1)/ nothing is coming. ls (hd0,msdos1) giving filesystem is ext2. Pls help. What will be the cause?

Comment: If it's returning nothing, or *unknown*, this probably means that grub_rescue is unable to read the file system type of a disk.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Then how is it possible to recover it?